# UWP - How to make Responsive Grid

Tags: windows, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I want to place items in a panel so that when screen size shrinks the items become visible by going down. In short I want to achieve "Float:left" of CSS, or what they do in Bootstrap?

anyway of Achieving that?

E-G of what I want to achieve.
https://postimg.org/gallery/2p2y7b5tc/

As there might be many items so I can't code manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special to enable this, just use the GridView control, and it will take care of everything

Try this sample:
https://github.com/TareqAteik/ResponsiveGrid

Comment: Thanks I didnt know about that control, I m just starting thats why.